# ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable error when I start the Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, execjs

I have created a new Rails application. When I try to start the server I get the following error:

```
[bathakarai@Project1-CO samp]$ rails server
/home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/gold/Ruby/Practice/Rails/samp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/bathakarai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sudo gem install therubyracer
```

or

```
gem install therubyracer
```

Hope this helps

Comment: After install therubyracer gem, run bundle or bundle install command. Once successful installation add "gem 'therubyracer'" line in Gemfile which is located inside the project

Comment: OK but what if I don't use coffee-script and don't want execjs? Sprockets depends on execjs, but does rails 4 need sprockets? Can I just pull the plug on execjs?

Comment: Great solution @Bathakarai! [Here](https://gist.github.com/lucio-martinez/23110e3618c1bac7f641) is a snippet to quickly solve it :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you've just generated a new application, this can come up when the gem `therubyracer` is commented.  It is needed to compile your assets.  You can uncomment that or install something like `nodejs` so you won't need to use the gem in all of your projects.

```
brew install nodejs
# or
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: For installing nodejs both the commends are not working @jvnill

Comment: are you perhaps using windows?

Answer (score 1):

The most popular JavaScript runtime is `therubyracer` which is a gem. As *@muttonlamb* [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15515425), install it running:

```
gem install therubyracer
```

Then, as *Bathakarai* [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15515180/#comment21973798_15515425), add the next line into your `Gemfile` at the bottom of the file:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Now run `rails server` again and everything should be working.

To simplify the process you can run [a script](https://gist.github.com/lucio-martinez/23110e3618c1bac7f641) to generate the app and add the JS runtime automatically.