# Can you help me why this error is happening when i try to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/salmanalam/MyProject/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515180/execjsruntimeunavailable-error-when-i-starts-rails-server?rq=1

Comment: As the error message suggests, you don't have any "JavaScript runtime" installed. Try installing Node.js

Answer (score 1):

There is no gem present to compile js code. you can use `gem rubyracer` or node which will help in compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this error But when I installed [NPN](https://npmjs.org/) or Node js I solved your error please try it. I hope it solves the error.